# How to perform a completable and then return a processed result with single?

Tags: java, api, io, rx-java, rx-java2

I hope my question is clear enough.

Let's say your have an API that performs requests over a network backed by IO-streams (input and output).

Using RxJava (which I am debuting with), I would think it could be possible to do the following:

```
public Single<MyData> getMyDataFromApi() {

    return requestMyData()
           .map/flat/then()->waitAndprocessData() // here is the missing link for me. What can I use ?
           .andThen()->returnData()
```

As you will understand, the method `requestMyData` returns a `Completable` which sole responsibility and only task it to perform said request (IO-type operation).

Then, upon performing the request, the remote entity shall process it and return a result the requested `MyData` object by performing an IO-type operation as well.

The key-point here, is that I work with **streams** (both input and output) which reading and writing operations are obviously performed in separate IO threads (using `Schedulers.io()`).

So in the end, is there a way so that my `getMyDataFromApi()` method does the following :

1. Perform the request -> it's a `completable`
2. Wait for the result -> something like a subscribe ? but without splitting the chain
3. Process the result -> it's a `single` or can be a lambada in `map` method
4. Return the result  -> final element, obviously a `single`

To conclude, I strongly believe that `requestMyData`'s signature should be that of a `Single`, because it's getter and I am expecting a result or an error.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations

Comment: Thank you for the link. I seem to get it but the problem is that I have to have a `Completable` in the mix and so it returns nothing ... because there is nothing to return. I am basically writing bytes in an `outputstream` and I am awaiting the result by reading from the `inputstream`.

Comment: Why don't you have requestMyData as Single instead so you get the data back when it is ready?

Comment: It is a single (based on it's signature) because I was expecting to chain a method that would actually wait for the result and return it. But i guess I could try and create a single that listen for the incoming data. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 0):

Without having the implementation of the methods is quite hard to understand the real problem. 
If `requestMyData` returns a `Completable` and `waitAndprocessData` a `Single`, you can do the following:

```
return requestMyData().andThen(waitAndprocessData());
```

Anyway remember that a `Completable` is computation without any value but only indication for completion (or exceptions).

Comment: Thank you for answer I understand your point. The problem I have is that I have two operations, that are completely asynchronous and there is **no way** I can make them synchronous. I have an **inputstream** from which I block-read incoming data for as long as the connection is alive and an **outputstream** from which I write data to send. So  when I `requestMyData()` I am effectively writing bytes **out** and when the answer comes **in**, the block-read releases and returns the result then starts block-reading again for next requests. So, two async operations, how can I _join_ them ?

Comment: Meanwhile, the solution I found is starting a second chain with a `SingleSubject` that triggers when the data is ready. I'll have to keep doing that for now as I have now way of chaining both operations. Especially since I want / must have only **one reader** to make sure data is properly ready, in the right order.